FAILURE Build failed with an exception in flutter
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:

Build file 'C:\Users\HP\StudioProjects\Doctor_Appointmnent_App\android\app\build.gradle' line: 9
I

What went wrong:

A problem occurred evaluating project': app'.

Could not get unknown property 'buildToolsVersion' for extension 'flutter of type FlutterExtension.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.


Run with --info or-debug option to get more log output


Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\HP\StudioProjects\Doctor_Appointmnent_App\android\app\build.gradle' line: 9

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.



Could not get unknown property 'buildToolsVersion' for extension 'flutter' of type FlutterExtension.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Try using flutter fvm to run a different version of flutter on that project. It's likely because of incompatible versions

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
